# Sort Collection By id set

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have an array of ids that i want to sort a given column by them in the collection.

For example,

```
$suppliersOrder = [8,7,5,1,3,4];

$items = Items::get()->sortBy(function($model) use ($suppliersOrder) {
   return array_search($model->supplier_id, $suppliersOrder);
})->values();
```

This acts like ordering items as `[1,3,4,5,7,8]` instead of the given order. And if I try sortByDesc, likewise `[8,7,5,4,3,1]` but I couldn't figure out the way to actually sort them as my given array's order.

My ultimate goal is then running `$items->groupBy('supplier.name')` so I can have my desired order.

---

What Alexander Villalobos suggested in the comments, I changed my code like this:

```
$items = Items::get()->sortBy(function($model) use ($suppliersOrder) {
   return rsort($model->supplier_id, $suppliersOrder);
});
```

> Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Item::$supplier_id has no effect

Comment: remove `array_search` and try for `rsort()` is a function `php` for sortby desc on `array`

Comment: `return rsort($model->supplier_id, $suppliersOrder`) gives me "Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Item::supplier_id has no effect"

Comment: you have one `example` result what do you want.

Comment: I want to order my collection by my given array of ids (as models' supplier_id column). Order by `model->supplier_id` as [8,7,5,1,3,4] - not [1,3,4,5,7,8] or [8,7,5,4,3,1] which I'd use `sortBy('supplier_id')`;

Comment: try delete property `->values()`

Comment: Still same error "Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Item::supplier_id has no effect"

Comment: inside `function` need pass `$key` `function ($model, $key) use ($suppliersOrder)`

Comment: Can you add an answer describing your solution? I think I understood how to use it wrong. Using `$key function ($model, $key) use ($suppliersOrder)` and `rsort($key, $ids)` would give me "$key should be an array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$suppliersOrder = [8,7,5,1,3,4];

$items = Items::get()->sortBy(function($row,$key) use ($suppliersOrder) {
   return array_search($row->supplier_id, $suppliersOrder);
});
```

This should give you sorted collection of items by the order you described in `$suppliersOrder`. As per [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby), the parameters to the callback function include one being the `row` for the collection and another being the `key` of that row in the collection.